# A form of appealing to nature?

Tags: logic, ethics, fallacies

I'm wondering if you could say that this is a from of the Natural fallacy:

Example 1:
Evolution has made us omnivorous, therefore eating meat is correct.

Example 2:
Animals eat animals, I'm an animal, therefore it's not unethical to eat animals.

It's indirectly saying that because it's like this in nature or made like this by nature it's 'better/justified' or accepted morals. Am I completely off?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, this is a form of the naturalistic fallacy; no, you're not completely off. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturalistic_fallacy):

> The naturalistic fallacy is the idea that what is found in nature is good.

Your examples do claim that something (eating meat; eating animals) is good because it's found in nature (history of the human race; other animals).